# Sencha Touch: how to refresh data of a component after setData()?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

For my mobile application I use Sencha Touch. I created a component to display a table.

Code of my component:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.components.table.Table', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
xtype: 'table',

config: {
cls: 'myTableCSS',
scrollable: 'vertical',
tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
    '<tpl for=".">',
        '<table>',
            '<tr>',
                '<tpl for="headers">',
                    '<th>{html}</th>',
                '</tpl>',
            '</tr>',
            '<tpl for="rows">',
                '<tr>',
                    '<tpl for="columns">',
                            '<td>{html}</td>',
                    '</tpl>',
                '</tr>',
            '</tpl>',
        '</table>',
    '</tpl>'
}
});
```

Code of my view implementation:

```
xtype: 'table',
id: 'myRedTable',
data: [
    {
        headers: [
            { html: 'firstname' },
            { html: 'lastname' },
            { html: 'age' }
        ],
        rows: [
            {
                columns: [
                    { html: 'John' },
                    { html: 'Smith' },
                    { html: '38' },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
],
```

Code of my controller which makes the AJAX request to load data from the server:

```
getResultFromServer: function(jsonResult) {
    var persons = jsonResult.getParameter('persons');
    this.getTable().setData(persons);
},
```

When I load the application and I go to my screen for the first time (after data loaded from the server by the AJAX request), I have my data displayed well on screen.

However, when I naviguate into the application and I come back to the screen, a new request to the server is done to refresh data on screen but the table is not refresh after the `setData();`.

How to refresh `data` of a component created with `tpl` `config` attribute?

P.S. : I don't have a `store`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was elsewhere and the `setData();` worked well. It was a cache problem with `Ext.get()` method.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 small notes which may give you a clue to solve the issue:

1. Why do you have to extend `Ext.Container` while it's better to extend `Ext.dataview.DataView`? I'm pretty sure you wanted to display a view with associated data, and `Ext.DataView` is the best way to go.
2. In case your view's data is populated from the `data` object, it'll be working if you use `yourDataView.refresh()` method to reload the data source and re-render your view.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I use a container to display a `<table>` HTML element. The list is not adapted in my case, I want displaying data with headers and cells with adapted size in relation to data inside.